# Facebook release key hash using eclipse

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am in the process of registering my android app in Facebook. This is to make my app to post a wall message to their Facebook page.

During this process it asks about the release key hash. In the eclipse when I try to export the signed application package I get finger print (MD5 and SHA1). Is this the one we have to use in Facebook android app registration process.

I do not want to use keytool. Instead I need to use eclipse to get the release key needed for this process. Kindly assist.

Comment: I just know keytool only :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to generate key hash through code-

```
     void getHasKey()
     {
      //Get Has Key 
        try 
        {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your package name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) 
            {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.e("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } 
        catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is that the HASH key different from the  MD5 and SHA1 shown in  finger print while creating the signed application package in eclipse

Comment: this is the keyhash which you have to add their while adding the application and yes its different from MD5 and SHA1.

Comment: @iappmaker for more detail, you can refer this- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/
Hope this will help you.

Comment: I understand this code snippet will give me the hash key. But Do i need to check it in signed APK or unsigned APK which will be used for debugging / testing

Comment: You mean the Key hash value will be same for both the signed / debug version

Comment: So the Key hash value is independent of the signature ? It depends only on the package name ?

Comment: This snip code just print the key hash for debug only, when sign and release your app to play store, you must add realse keyhash, to get release keyhash, you must genarate with your release keystore, like this: keytool -exportcert -alias MY_ALIAS_HERE -keystore ~/path/to/my/android.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 Gluck

Comment: If you are going to do with the signed package you get the real key